# Dennett's view on the effect language has on the mind/brain

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, language, cognitive-sciences, knowledge-representation, neurophilosophy

Several years ago, while studying philosophy, I recall reading in numerous sources that Dennett believed (or was interpreted as believing - by either Clark or Churchland [or Fodor?]) that it was language that basically transformed the brain into a symbolic machine (to loosely paraphrase - the point was that language had a massively transformative effect on the brain [or mind, I don't care which he referred to]).

Unfortunately, I no longer have any of the books/articles that I was reading back then, so I can't go back and check them all. I've been searching online for a day now and have been unable to track down any of these sources.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. It was Clark paraphrasing him, in (at least) two articles:

- Magic Words: How Language Augments Human Computation (1998): http://www.philosophy.ed.ac.uk/people/clark/pubs/magic.pdf
- Linguistic Anchors in the Sea of Thought (1996): http://www.philosophy.ed.ac.uk/people/clark/pubs/linguist.pdf

As [Rex Kerr](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/10279/5750) suggested, it was indeed from *Consciousness Explained*. For instance, here is a quote from Clark's 1996 paper:

> "Dennett depicts our exposure to linguistic bombardment (in the context of some small and subtle differences in initial hardware) as causing the development of a special kind of on-board computational device viz. a kind of classical serial processor implemented in the substrate of massively parallel, broadly connectionist, neural machinery."

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.  I recall reading Dennett advocating or at least open to the idea that language structures the brain's other workings to a significant extent, though.  One example is posted [here](http://amiquote.tumblr.com/post/1204081693/daniel-dennett-on-the-role-of-language-in).

I do not recall reading anything by Churchland that was paraphrasing this, and I haven't read enough Fodor or Clark to know if they would have.

Comment: Hmmm, this is very frustrating. I'm positive he was more explicit at some point, but I dunno why I can't find it. It must have been someone paraphrasing him... perhaps it was somewhere in the connectionist vs. computational debate. Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion!